Google Forms обновляет диапазон и стирает формулу в таблице, как решить?
Долго не могу решить казалось бы простую задачу...


Да нет вроде, или подскажите пожалуйста что это

Не сработал вариант

Пропишите свою формулу в заголовке, и тогда затирания формой вашей формулы не будет:
={"Прибыль";ARRAYFORMULA(ЕСЛИ(I2:I="";;I2:I-J2:J))}

